# Laravel Carbon addHours response modification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a booking table where there's a bookingtime datetime field and duration field.

The duration field is integer.

In my get query for the calendar, I am showing the duration so I am trying to :
add the duration to the booking time date.

I am using this in the end of my query:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($query);$i++){
$durationdate =  Carbon::parse($query[$i]->bookingtime)->addHours($query[$i]->duration);
$query[$i]->end = $durationdate;
}
return $query.
```

The query is returning everything fine. but the "end" is returning an object
end{ date:"..." , timezone_type:3, timezon: "UTC"}

I want to modify the end to be returned like the other data in my query response as :
end : "2018-02-01 12:00:00"  for example

Answer (score 1):

Use the `toDateTimeString()` method like this:

```
$query[$i]->end = $durationdate->toDateTimeString();
```

Or the `format()` method:

```
$query[$i]->end = $durationdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Still returning an object end{};

Answer (score 0):

The object returns is of type `DateTime`, so you can use the `format()` function to get the expect date `2018-02-01 12:00:00`

```
$query[$i]->end = $durationdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```